# Merge Nuclei and Cell rows together in a data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have a dataset that consist on nuclei and cells.

Some columns are unique to nuclei or cells and some columns where there are readings for both

```
ParentType ObjectType ObjectID ParentID Area CytoplasmArea Dye1Intensity
WholeCell  Nuclei     1        1        10   NA            500
Well       WholeCell  1        1        100  90            NA
WholeCell  Nuclei     2        2        20   NA            550
Well       WholeCell  2        1        120  100           NA
```

I wanted to merge the rows of the data in such a way that I will only have nuclei data with its corresponding wholecell data represented as new columns.

Corresponding meaning the **Nuclei's ParentID must match the WholeCell's ObjectID**. This is to indicate that the nuclei belong to this cell.

For now, I wish to give keep things simple where one nuclei should belong to only one parent

The results should be like this:

```
ParentType ObjectType ObjectID ParentID ObjectArea ParentArea ParentCytoplasmArea ObjectDye1Intensity
WholeCell  Nuclei     1        1        10         100        90                  500
WholeCell  Nuclei     2        2        20         120        100                 550
```

An idea I could think of is to split the dataset into Nuclei and WholeCells data separately, change the column names for both dataset and use a for loop on every nuclei on the data to get what I want but I understand that data frame and data table has many useful function like merge, join or aggregate to do this task in an efficient manner.

Could someone recommend me a useful way to do this better ?

My starting code:

```
dt <- data.table(ParentType=c("WholeCell","Well","WholeCell","Well"),ObjectType=c("Nuclei","WholeCell","Nuclei","WholeCell"),ObjectID=c(1,1,2,2),ParentID=c(1,1,2,1),Area=c(10,100,20,120),CytoplasmArea=c(NA,90,NA,100),Dye1Intensity=c(500,NA,550,NA))
Nuclei = dt[which(dt$ObjectType=="Nuclei"),]
Cells =  dt[which(dt$ObjectType=="WholeCell"),]
setnames(Nuclei,names(Nuclei),paste0("Object", names(Nuclei)))
setnames(Cells,names(Cells),paste0("Parent", names(Cells)))
```